# How do you get current active/default Environment profile programmatically in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-profiles

I need to code different logic based on different current Environment profile.

***How can you get the currently active and default profiles from Spring?***

Comment: @aweigold: get current active/default Environment profile programatically in spring 3.1. what more details you need?

Answer (score 346, accepted):

You can autowire the [`Environment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html)

```
@Autowired
Environment env;
```

`Environment` offers:

- [`String[] getActiveProfiles()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html#getActiveProfiles--),
- [`String[] getDefaultProfiles()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html#getDefaultProfiles--), and
- [`boolean acceptsProfiles(String... profiles)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html#acceptsProfiles-java.lang.String...-)

Comment: How can I get such thing in **static** methods in **non-spring-managed** classes?

Comment: I'd try adding the profile-name as a method parameter and pass it from the calling class.

Comment: Looks like Spring 5.1 deprecated `acceptsProfiles(String... profiles)` and replaced it with `acceptsProfiles(Profiles profiles)`.

Answer (score 148):

Extending User1648825's nice simple answer:

```
@Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
private String activeProfile;
```

This may throw an IllegalArgumentException if no profiles are set (I get a null value). This may be a Good Thing if you need it to be set; if not use the 'default' syntax for @Value, ie:

```
@Value("${spring.profiles.active:Unknown}")
private String activeProfile;
```

...activeProfile now contains 'Unknown' if spring.profiles.active could not be resolved

Comment: Profile names are separated by a comma. Checkout https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles#2-using-springactiveprofile

Comment: It doesn't work when making get injected in SpringBootTest. Injecting Environment works

Comment: see discussion on `@SpringBootTest` and `@ActiveProfiles` and why/how it was changed from Spring Boot 2.3 onwards [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19788)

Answer (score 76):

Here is a more complete example.

**Autowire Environment**

First you will want to autowire the environment bean.

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
```

**Check if Profiles exist in Active Profiles**

Then you can use `getActiveProfiles()` to find out if the profile exists in the list of active profiles.  Here is an example that takes the `String[]` from `getActiveProfiles()`, gets a stream from that array, then uses matchers to check for multiple profiles(Case-Insensitive) which returns a boolean if they exist.

```
//Check if Active profiles contains "local" or "test"
if(Arrays.stream(environment.getActiveProfiles()).anyMatch(
   env -> (env.equalsIgnoreCase("test") 
   || env.equalsIgnoreCase("local")) )) 
{
   doSomethingForLocalOrTest();
}
//Check if Active profiles contains "prod"
else if(Arrays.stream(environment.getActiveProfiles()).anyMatch(
   env -> (env.equalsIgnoreCase("prod")) )) 
{
   doSomethingForProd();
}
```

You can also achieve similar functionality using the annotation `@Profile("local")` Profiles allow for selective configuration based on a passed-in or environment parameter.  Here is more information on this technique: [Spring Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

Comment: @Profile seems like the best solution.

Answer (score 38):

```
@Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
private String activeProfile;
```

It works and you don't need to implement EnvironmentAware. But I don't know drawbacks of this approach.

Comment: This line gives this error: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.profiles.active' in value "${spring.profiles.active}"`

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Using Spring Boot 1.5.15.

Comment: I think if the profile is defined, value will be parsed, otherwise the exception arises. Does not fit all situations.

Comment: Active profile also could be an array, take attention to that please. Using such way you can get unexpected error on adding additional profiles.

Comment: The drawback to this approach is that it won't get all of the profiles that Spring might consider when evaluating `@Profile`. Apps can also use the `spring.profiles.include` 
 property, and can set profiles programmatically during initialization using `ConfigurableEnvironment`. `Environment.getActiveProfiles()` will get the full list of profiles set using any of these mechanisms.

Comment: I am getting null

Comment: make sure that application.yml the property sets correctly

Answer (score 23):

As already mentioned earlier. You could autowire **Environment**:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
```

only you could do check for the needed environment much easier:

```
if (environment.acceptsProfiles(Profiles.of("test"))) {
    doStuffForTestEnv();
} else {
    doStuffForOtherProfiles();
}
```

Answer (score 17):

If you're not using autowiring, simply implement `EnvironmentAware`

Comment: Works only if the class implementing the interface is managed by Spring.

Answer (score 11):

Seems there is some demand to be able to access this statically.

> How can I get such thing in static methods in non-spring-managed
>   classes? – Aetherus

It's a hack, but you can write your own class to expose it. You must be careful to ensure that nothing will call `SpringContext.getEnvironment()` before all beans have been created, since there is no guarantee when this component will be instantiated.

```
@Component
public class SpringContext
{
    private static Environment environment;

    public SpringContext(Environment environment) {
        SpringContext.environment = environment;
    }

    public static Environment getEnvironment() {
        if (environment == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Environment has not been set yet");
        }
        return environment;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that was helpful since i need it on a static method!

Answer (score 7):

And if you neither want to use @Autowire nor injecting @Value you can simply do (with fallback included):

```
System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active", "unknown");
```

This will return any active profile (or fallback to 'unknown').

Comment: This does not work for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me either

Comment: I guess the spring.profiles.active must be set as VM argument to make it work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

with spring 5.3.28, things could be simpler:

1. autowire `Environment`;
2. use `boolean matchesProfiles(String... profileExpressions)`;

for example:

```java
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

...

if (env.matchesProfiles("online")) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

#### use service in spring boot

```
@Service
class ProfileService(
    val environment: Environment
) {
    fun get(): Profile? {
        return Profile[environment.activeProfiles.firstOrNull()]
    }

    fun isTest(): Boolean {
        return get() != Profile.PRD
    }
}
```