# Setting the default active profile in Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want my default active profile to be `production` if `-Dspring.profiles.active` is not set.

I tried the following in my `application.properties` but it did't work:

```
spring.profiles.default=production
```

Spring-boot version = 1.3.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 126, accepted):

What you are doing here is setting the default **default** profile (the profile that is used on any bean if you don't specify the `@Profile` annotation) to be `production`.

What you actually need to do is set the default **active** profile, which is done like this:

```
spring.profiles.active=production
```

Comment: That worked and argument `-Dspring.profiles.active=development` overrides it, which is what I wanted

Comment: @PaulNUK what is mean by 'production' here??

Comment: production is just the name of a profile (it could be any valid profile). As the original question asked how to set the active profile to production, that's what I put in the answer.

Answer (score 30):

add `--spring.profiles.active=production`

Example:

```
java -jar file.jar --spring.profiles.active=production
```

Comment: This is the solution for me. Previously, I tried `java -jar file.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=production`, but that wouldn't work for me.

Comment: if you are intrested with -D args style it should preceed as below java -Dspring.profiles.active=production -jar file.jar

Comment: Indeed, using -D didn't work for me either, using --spring.profiles.active for command line arguments did.

Answer (score 27):

First of all, with the solution below, is necessary to understand that **always the spring boot will read the `application.properties`** file. So the other's profile files **only will complement and replace** the properties defined before.

Considering the follow files:

```
application.properties
application-qa.properties
application-prod.properties
```

1) Very important. The `application.properties`, and **just this file**, must have the follow line:

```
spring.profiles.active=@spring.profiles.active@
```

2) Change what you want in the QA and PROD configuration files to see the difference between the environments.

3) By command line, start the spring boot app with any of this options:

It will start the app with the default `application.properties` file:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

It will load the default `application.properties` file and after the `application-qa.properties` file, replacing and/or complementing the default configuration:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=qa
```

The same here but with the production environment instead of QA:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
```

Comment: For this solution is not necessary change Java files.

Answer (score 14):

We to faced similar issue while setting `spring.profiles.active` in java.

This is what we figured out in the end, after trying four different ways of providing `spring.profiles.active`.

In `java-8`

```
$ java --spring.profiles.active=dev -jar my-service.jar
Gives unrecognized --spring.profiles.active option.
```

```
$ java -jar my-service.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev
# This works fine
```

```
$ java -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar my-service.jar
# This works fine
```

```
$ java -jar my-service.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
# This doesn't works
```

In `java-11`

```
$ java --spring.profiles.active=dev -jar my-service.jar
Gives unrecognized --spring.profiles.active option.
```

```
$ java -jar my-service.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev
# This doesn't works
```

```
$ java -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar my-service.jar
# This works fine
```

```
$ java -jar my-service.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
# This doesn't works
```

**NOTE:** If you're specifying `spring.profiles.active` in your `application.properties` file then make sure you provide `spring.config.location` or `spring.config.additional-location` option to java accordingly as mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you. For me on java 11 is working just the one you mentioned: 'java -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar my-service.jar'

Answer (score 12):

If you're using maven I would do something like this:

Being **production** your default profile:

```
<properties>
    <activeProfile>production</activeProfile>
</properties>
```

And as an example of other profiles:

```
<profiles>
    <!--Your default profile... selected if none specified-->
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <activeProfile>production</activeProfile>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <!--Profile 2-->
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <properties>
            <activeProfile>development</activeProfile>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <!--Profile 3-->
    <profile>
        <id>otherprofile</id>
        <properties>
            <activeProfile>otherprofile</activeProfile>
        </properties>
    </profile>
<profiles>
```

In your application.properties you'll have to set:

```
spring.profiles.active=@activeProfile@
```

This works for me every time, hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Note - to use profile use `maven package -P{profilename}` - e.g. `maven package -Pproduction` for production based profile.

Comment: Does this automatically works without specify the profile at run time as mention Artegon just above. Does this really works to set activeByDefault to true without passing profile from commandline? for me using activeByDefault is not working..

Comment: Any idea how to do this with yml? Doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Jackie - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66631458/3059685

Comment: How can we achieve that only the active properties file will be part of the final jar? In our case there is sensible credential information (such as client IDs and client secrets) inside the dev profile that I don't want to expose to customers. Is there a way to exclude properties files based on the active maven profile?

Comment: Found the solution to my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55286988/spring-boot-maven-plugin-exclude-properties-file-from-final-jar

Answer (score 10):

I do it this way

```
    System.setProperty("spring.profiles.default", "dev");
```

in the very beginning of `main(...)`

Comment: Personally, I prefer to reference constant `org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.DEFAULT_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME` instead of it's value.

Answer (score 9):

Put this in the App.java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(App.class);
    SimpleCommandLinePropertySource source = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);
    if (!source.containsProperty("spring.profiles.active") &&
            !System.getenv().containsKey("SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE")) {

        app.setAdditionalProfiles("production");
    }
    ...
}
```

This is how it is done in JHipster

Comment: Works for setting profile in aws lambda programmatically. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The neat way to do this without changing your source code each time is to use the OS environment variable `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE`:

```sh
export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=production
```

[how-to-set-active-spring-profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-set-active-spring-profiles)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using AWS Lambda with SprintBoot,  then you must declare the following under environment variables:

key: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS & value: -Dspring.profiles.active=dev

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **application.yml** for your config then add this to it, to set the default active profile:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: production
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently using Maven + Spring Boot. Our solution was the following:

application.properties

```
#spring.profiles.active= # comment_out or remove
```

securityConfig.java

```
@Value(${spring.profiles.active:[default_profile_name]}")
private String ACTIVE_PROFILE_NAME;
```

Credit starts with [MartinMlima](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3979886/martinmlima). Similar answer provided here:

[How do you get current active/default Environment profile programmatically in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267799/how-do-you-get-current-active-default-environment-profile-programmatically-in-sp?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

One can have separate application properties files according to the environment, if Spring Boot application is being created.
For example - properties file for dev environment,
**application-dev.properties**:

```
spring.hivedatasource.url=<hive dev data source url>
spring.hivedatasource.username=dev
spring.hivedatasource.password=dev
spring.hivedatasource.driver-class-name=org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
```

**application-test.properties:**

```
spring.hivedatasource.url=<hive dev data source url>
spring.hivedatasource.username=test
spring.hivedatasource.password=test
spring.hivedatasource.driver-class-name=org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
```

And a primary application.properties file to select the profile:

**application.properties:**

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
server.tomcat.max-threads = 10
spring.application.name=sampleApp
```

Define the DB Configuration as below:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.hivedatasource")
public class DBConfig {

    @Profile("dev")
    @Qualifier("hivedatasource")
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource devHiveDataSource() {
        System.out.println("DataSource bean created for Dev");
        return new BasicDataSource();
    }

    @Profile("test")
    @Qualifier("hivedatasource")
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource testHiveDataSource() {
        System.out.println("DataSource bean created for Test");
        return new BasicDataSource();
    }
```

This will automatically create the BasicDataSource bean according to the active profile set in application.properties file.
Run the Spring-boot application and test.

Note that this will create an empty bean initially until getConnection() is called.
Once the connection is available you can get the url, driver-class, etc. using that DataSource bean.

Comment: The beauty of the profiles for application properties is that you can have multiple mutually exclusive sets of properties. So you don't need to define two beans. Just define one without `@Profile` and it'll get properties corresponding to the active profile.

Answer (score 1):

you can also have multiple listings in the @Profile annotation

```
@Profile({"dev","default"})
```

If you set "default" as an additional value, you don't have to specify spring.profiles.active

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`@PropertySource("classpath:${spring.profiles.active:production}_file.properties")`

Answer (score 0):

**In AWS LAMBDA:**

For `$ sam local` you add the following line in your sam template yml file:

```
Resources:
   FunctionName:
       Properties:
           Environment:
               Variables:
                  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: local
```

But in AWS Console:
in your Lambda Environment variables just add:

KEY:`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` VALUE:`-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone out there trying to load profile-specific properties for spring web(not boot)
Then do this, can add multiple profiles to pom. Then in config class we can read the build profile and load props accordingly

> build like mvn clean install -Pdev

pom.xml

```
<profiles>
<profile>
            <id>prod</id>
             <properties>
                <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <!-- activate if system properties 'env=prod' -->
            </activation>
            <build><finalName>Finger</finalName></build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

class

```
    @Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
public class MyApplicationConfiguration {
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/application.properties");
    try {
        Properties props1 = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
        resource = new ClassPathResource("/application-"+props1.getProperty("spring.profiles.active")+".properties");
        configurer.setProperties(props1);
        configurer.setLocation(resource);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return configurer;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=foo,bar
java -Dspring.profiles.active=development -jar yourApplication.jar
```

Both the above works whereas `-Dspring-boot.run.profiles` won't work with `mvn test`

but after setting env varaible `export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=development` will work with `mvn test`

btw `mvn -P` is for maven profile not a spring profile