# How to get active Spring profile set from Maven Build Profile?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I am using Maven inside Eclipse to build and deploy code. I have multiple profiles setup "production","dev" & "test" in the pom.xml. The question is, is there anyway I can get the currently using profile name/id (which is the one passed as the Maven Build Profiles param from Eclipse Run Configurations) from Spring MVC application.

I have tried autowiring `org.springframework.core.env.Environment` and use `getActiveProfiles()` as answered in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9268041/1102004) but the String array returned is empty.

[image]

Comment: maven profiles / spring profiles are different things

Comment: One option is to define a property specific for each maven profile and use that, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500533/access-maven-properties-defined-in-the-pom for example. You also could set the property  `spring.profiles.active` (for each profile in the pom) and use spring profile, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38520638/how-to-set-spring-profile-from-system-variable for example

Comment: `maven profiles / spring profiles are different things` this comment made me realize i'm doing it all wrong.. Thank you @RC.