# @Conditional default value based on Spring profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have this in my Java code.If fieldOne is not present in properties file
1)In prod environment(application_prod.yml) --fieldOne value should be true
2)For all other environment (application_uat.yml/application_int.yml)--fieldOne value should be false.

How to achieve it?

```
@Value("${fieldOne:true}")
 private String fieldOne;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get current active/default Environment profile programmatically in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267799/how-do-you-get-current-active-default-environment-profile-programmatically-in-sp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `application.yml` to provide a default value that's overridden by profile specific files.

The order in which spring evaluates external configuration is documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).